# Violin plot: How is the adjacent value range determined, and why is it different from boxplot?

Tags: r, boxplot, violin-plot, iqr

In theory the violinplot of vioplot package is a boxplot + density function.

In the "boxplot part",

- the black box corresponds to the IQR (indeed, see below), and
- the midline should correspond to the same range (adjacent values, default 1.5 IQR), yet it is not (see below). Anyone can explain why are they different?

  ```
  require("vioplot")
  a = rnorm(100)
  range (a)
  a = c(a,2,8,2.9,3,4, -3, -5) # add some outliers

  par ( mfrow = c(1,2))
  boxplot(a, range=1.5)
  vioplot(a, range=1.5 )
  ```

Benerated by above:

[image: Box vs Vio generated by above lines]

[Hintze, J. L. and R. D. Nelson (1998). Violin plots: a box plot-density trace synergism. The American Statistician, 52(2):181-4.](http://amstat.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00031305.1998.10480559)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me illustrate this with a simple example:

```
b <- c(1:10, 20)

par(mfrow = c(1,2))
boxplot(b, range=1.5)
vioplot(b, range=1.5 )
```

[image]

The definition of R's boxplot is (borrowing from [ggplot's help](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/blob/master/R/geom-boxplot.r) on the topic):

> The upper whisker extends from the hinge to the highest value that is within
>   1.5 * IQR of the hinge, where IQR is the inter-quartile range, or distance
>   between the first and third quartiles.

Browsing the [source code](https://github.com/cran/vioplot/blob/master/R/vioplot.R) of vioplot, we see `upper[i] <- min(q3[i] + range*iqd, data.max)`.

Therefore, let us try to reproduce the upper whisker value:

```
# vioplot draws
quantile(b, 0.75) + 1.5 * IQR(b)
# 16

# boxplot draws
max(b[b <= quantile(b, 0.75) + 1.5 * IQR(b)])
# 10
```

Comment: Thanks, especially for the reproduction examples! So, **in vioplot**, the min () function only protects no to draw the adjacent-value line beyond the very last data point, whereas **in boxplot**, checks the actual highest values within the +1.5*IQR range, therefore it is more meaningful for your actual data.